# Using format specifiers

Tags: java

can this code:

```
 log.info(">>> start http request partner: " + requestWrapper.getPartnerId() + " : " + requestWrapper.getPartner());
```

be replaced with this:

```
log.info(">>> start http request partner: " + requestWrapper.getPartnerId() + " : " + requestWrapper.getPartner());
```

to be replaced with

```
log.info(">>> start http request partner: {} : {} rquestWrapper.getPartnerId(), requestWrapper.getPartner();
```

Comment: What is log? Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It depends on the supported methods of your `log` instance. If it's a Logger from SLF4J then yes. see: https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your log object is an instance of `java.util.logging.Logger` class, you can do the following

```java
log.log(Level.INFO, "{0} {1}", new String[]{"Hello", "World"});
```

which outputs

```
Jul 26, 2019 3:39:09 PM example.Test main
INFO: Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some kind of string interpolation, then using `String.format` should do it:

```
log.info(String.format("start http request partner: %s : %s", requestWrapper.getPartnerId(), requestWrapper.getPartner()));
```